# Getting 403 forbidden error using @PostMapping via rest api in spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, post

I am getting 403 forbidden error on postman while accessing `@PostMapping`. However, `@GetMapping` is working fine with basic authentication

```
@PostMapping(value = { "/version" })
@ApiOperation(value = "Set Version")
@Monitor(useCase = "setApplicationVersion")
public void setApplicationVersion() {
   System.out.println("Hey postman");

}
```

This is my `@PostMapping method`. Suggest something for the issue

Comment: You'll probably have to show your Spring security configuration.

Comment: I used the above in my pom

Comment: Don't add additional code/xml as comments, instead use the edit button on your question.

Comment: Do you send json with Postman. If yes, you can add in that Postmapping annotation parameters : `consumes = "application/json; charset=UTF-8"`

Answer (score 0):

Please post screenshot of what kind of request is being sent via postman and the type of content we are sending as same needs to be set at the controller level.

check if content type is set to application/json in the controller and when sending request from postman.